# Solve complex equations in R

Tags: r

I have an equation like where a, b, c and d are constants :

(b/(4.24*10^-11))*(1-2*x) + log(x/(1-x)) - log((a/(1-a))*c/d)) = 0

How can I solve this equation in R for finding x?

Comment: Have a look at https://palomar.home.ece.ust.hk/MAFS6010R_lectures/Rsession_solvers.html

Comment: you can use `uniroot`.

Comment: Are you trying to solve numerically for specific a,b,c,d or are you trying to find a symbolic solution where the answer is an expression involving symbols for a,b,c,d?

Comment: for specific a,b,c,d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Assuming that the constants all equal 0.1 and that the value of x which solves the equation lies between 0.1 and .9 we have:

```
f <- function(x, a, b, c, d) (b/(4.2410^-11))*(1-2*x) + 
  log(x/(1-x)) - log((a/(1-a))*c/d)
uniroot(f, c(0.1, 0.9), a = .1, b = .1, c = .1, d = .1)
str(ans)
```

giving:

```
List of 5
 $ root      : num 0.5
 $ f.root    : num -8.54e-07
 $ iter      : int 2
 $ init.it   : int NA
 $ estim.prec: num 6.1e-05
```

We can graph it like this:

```
curve(f(x, .1, .1, .1, .1), 0.1, 0.9)
abline(v = ans$root, h = ans$f.root)
```

[image: screenshot]

**2)** Another possibility is to rearrange the equation to give:

```
x = (+1+(log(x/(1-x)) - log((a/(1-a))*c/d)) / (b/(4.2410^-11)))/2
```

and then iterate that. Note that it immediately converged.

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- 0.1
x <- 0.25
for(i in 1:10) print(
    x <- (+1+(log(x/(1-x)) - log((a/(1-a))*c/d)) / (b/(4.2410^-11)))/2
  )
```

giving:

```
[1] 0.5000007
[1] 0.5000014
[1] 0.5000014
[1] 0.5000014
[1] 0.5000014
[1] 0.5000014
[1] 0.5000014
[1] 0.5000014
[1] 0.5000014
[1] 0.5000014
```